How do I color a two toned bar plot based on a two variables that add up to the total length of the bar?
I apologize for the confusing title - I wasn't quite sure how to phrase what I wanted.
The dataset that I am working on is a subdataset I created from my main data. It looks something like this:



Genre
meanGrossing
meanBudget
MaleGrossing




Family
1097910750
188821479
292776200


Action
1374979940
184161982
511320665



There are 16 other rows but this is just a small section of my dataset. Malegrossing is calculated for each genre. I am going to add another variable that calculates Femalegrossing - I know how to do this.
So far, the current dataset I am working with was obtained from the following code being repeated and 'cbind' for each genre. There where issues with the raw data I was using and this was the only way we could work with it instead of against it.
genre = "Animation", raw_data %>% filter(Animation == 1) %>% summarise(meangross = mean(InflatedGross),meanBudget = mean(InflatedBudget), Malegross = ((mean(Proportion_male))*meangross)))

The adding of the variables Malegrossing and Femalegrossing will always equal to meanGrossing.
I want to present the information in something like this:
Y axis is meangross. X axis is each genre category. Each bar graph is composed of two colors, blue and pink totaling up to the meangross showing how much they each make up the entire grossing.
Please let me know if more clarification is needed.

You have to reshape your data to tidy format so that you have a column containing the gender and a column containing the values. Then you can do something like ggplot(data, aes(genre, value, fill = gender)) + geom_col() to get the desired stacked barchart. For more help please provide a minimal reproducible example including a minimal but complete example code and a snippet of your input data best shared using dput(). As your question is about plotting, we don't need your data wrangling code.

Possible dups: Creating grouped bar-plot of multi-column data in R and How to create a ggplot bar chart with multiple columns of data for y?

Similar to what stefan said, if you can rearrange maleGross and femaleGross to be factors within a single column vector, might be able to do something akin to this:
ggplot(yourData, aes(x=genre, y=meangross, fill=GenderGross)) + 
geom_bar(stat="identity") + 
scale_fill_manual(values = c("pink", "blue"))

You may need to tweak the color order depending on how the rest of your data is structured, but the order can be switched in the scale_fill_manual vector once your data is re-arranged.
